# Setting up a firebase cloud function call

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set up cloud functions with firebase and I am having a slightly difficult time getting it set up.
I want to set up a function that gets called by an HTTP request. The function would take the information provided, double-check if those values are indeed the same values as the ones found in my firestorm
and then execute some Javascript code before responding; this is my code:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


// [START trigger]
exports.buyCrypto = functions.https.onRequest((request, res) => 
{
  // [END trigger]
  // [START sendError]
  // Forbidding PUT requests.
  if (request.method === 'PUT') {
    return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
  }
  // [END sendError]
  
    // [START readQueryParam]
    const uid = request.body.uid
    const crypto = request.body.crypto
    const amount = request.body.amount
    
    const docRef = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid);
    docRef.get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            if(crypto === "BTC")
            {
                if(doc.data.btc <= amount)
                {
                    //execute buy
                    return res.status(200).send("Sucess");
                }
            }
            if(crypto === "ETH")
            {
                if(doc.data.btc <= amount)
                {
                    //execute buy
                    return res.status(200).send("Sucess");
                }
            }
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
    
    // Push the new message into Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
    //const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({original: original});
    // Send back a message that we've successfully written the message
    
    // [START sendResponse]
    const formattedResponse =  "IDK"
    return res.status(403).send("Failed");
    // [END sendResponse]
});
```

Unfortunatly I cannot seem to find a great deal of documentation for firebase functions and when I try to test it with the emulator through a web browser it goes into infinite loading and does not display an error message so I am finding it impossible to debug anything.
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `return res.status(403).send("Failed");` outside of the `then()` block, so this line will be called before the asynchronous call to the `get()` method is completed and the Promise returned by this method is fulfilled. Result: your Cloud Function always sends back an error to its caller.

In addition, you do `doc.data.btc` instead of `doc.data().btc`. See the doc for the [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html), `data()` is a method.

Also, note that you don't need to use `return` in an HTTPS Cloud Function. Just send back a response with `res.redirect()`, `res.send()`, or `res.end()`. You may watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA.

The following should therefore do the trick:

```
exports.buyCrypto = functions.https.onRequest((request, res) => {
    if (request.method === 'PUT') {
        return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
    }
    const uid = request.body.uid
    const crypto = request.body.crypto
    const amount = request.body.amount

    const docRef = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid);
    docRef.get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            if (crypto === "BTC") {
                if (doc.data().btc <= amount) {
                    //execute buy
                    res.status(200).send("Success");
                } else {
                    // send a 200 response or throw an error  res.status(200).send("....");
                    // Depends on your functional requirements
                }
            } else if (crypto === "ETH") {
                if (doc.data.btc <= amount) {
                    //execute buy
                    return res.status(200).send("Success");
                } else {
                    // send a 200 response or throw an error  res.status(200).send("....");
                    // Depends on your functional requirements
                }
            } else {
                // send a 200 response or throw an error  res.status(200).send("....");
                // Depends on your functional requirements
            }
        } else {
            console.log("No such document!");
            // send a 200 response or throw an error  res.status(200).send("....");
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    });

});
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, I watched the video and it makes more sense now how HTTPS functions work. I only have one problem, I tried this approach and also the one from the video "const promise = admin.firestore().doc(dataPath).get();" with datapath = 'users/'+uid but unfortunatly it cannot find the document I need. I double checked my firestore, I have a users collection with documents names after the uid and it cannot find anything, is there some configuration that needs to be done for the admin.firestore object?

Comment: You should not have any problem with your code. You correctly do `const admin = require('firebase-admin'); admin.initializeApp();` and your query syntax is correct. Are you sure `uid` Has the correct value? What do you see if you do `console.log(uid);`?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/1f499b6da4836bc150391bf2420543f6 Here is a screenshot of all the info. On the left, I have my fire store data with users collection and the documents. On the left, I have the nodeJS terminal with the execution. I wrote a few console logs of the information that is sent to the function, I pull it out of the request body and print it and it seems all the information is there.

Comment: What happens if you deploy your function and run it without the emulator (calling the "real" endpoint, hosted on Firebase/GCP platform).

Comment: Actually, that is a good point, I never attempted it before. I am still on the free plan so I cannot deploy to a real endpoint until I upgrade to a pay as you go, model. So far I am only testing cloud functions with an app that might not go public. Would there be a difference between the emulator and the real endpoint?

Comment: [According to the Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#emulate-execution-of-your-functions), the Firebase  Emulator  allows you to build and test apps on your local machine instead of deploying to a Firebase project to prevent the risk from coding errors that could potentially incur cost in a production environment. So it should be working correctly with Emulator and makes no difference when deploying on a real endpoint.

Comment: Please have a look into the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46373682/8791788) which I think is your issue. You need to send a response even if it's empty to indicate that the function is done executing. So please check in every case, you are sending a response.